# Choosing a device name under /dev from the kernel command line

Tags: linux, boot, kickstart

I am booting CentOS via a USB install. The boot method is simply booting the ISO from GRUB2 installed on the USB Key and then grabbing a Kickstart file from a server in the net. 
The Kickstart file is supposed to format the first harddrive labled normally /dev/sda.
This works when I boot via CD, how ever, with the USB, the USB key always gets the "name" /dev/sda. 
So the kickstart tried to format the USB! Can I change that name from the kernel command line? instead of 
editing the the KS file ?

What would be the correct kernel boot paramerter to do this?

Just adding some info: When I boot Debian from an external USB hard-drive, that hard drive is labeled /dev/sdb, and the one inside the laptop is labeled /dev/sda. This really enhances my suspicion I can control the labels, but how ?

I know about udev rules, I don't want to change the udev rules inside the standard CentOS iso ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is propably the BIOS that places the USB-Stick as first boot device.
Try to change the start order to

1. First Harddisk (wipe out the MBR so it will NOT boot)
2. Second USB

Perhaps that will help to place your USB-Stick to "sdb".